# Youtube api with auth 2 in cron jobs

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, cron, youtube-api

I have created  a php script for fetching youtube videos data of my youtube channel including unlisted videos with the help of auth2.0 . My problem is how I run script in cron job without any user interaction?
Cant use service account as youtube api doesnt support it and how script chooses which account to choose ?

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
session_start();


if (!file_exists(__DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php')) {
  throw new Exception(sprintf('Please run "composer require google/apiclient:~2.0" in "%s"', __DIR__));
}

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName('youtubeproject');
$client->setDeveloperKey(" ");
$client->setAccessType('offline');
$client->setScopes([
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly',
]);
$client->setAuthConfig(' ');

//$client->setApprovalPrompt('consent');
//$client->setIncludeGrantedScopes(true);
$client->setPrompt('consent');
$client->setIncludeGrantedScopes(true);
$client->createAuthUrl();

if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) {
  $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);

  $youtube = new Google_Service_YouTube($client);
  


  $i=0;
  $pagetoken='';
  $pagetoken1='';
  youtube_calls_playlist($pagetoken);
  youtube_callsplaylistitems($pagetoken1);
} else {
        $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
  $redirect_uri = 'http://localhost/youtubeproject/' . 'oauth2callback.php/';
  header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}
function youtube_calls_playlist($pagetoken){
   
global $youtube;
global $total_ids;
if($pagetoken!=''){
       $queryParams_playlists = [
    'mine' => true,
    'pageToken'=> $pagetoken
     ];
}
else{
     $queryParams_playlists = [
    'mine' => true,
    ];
}
$response_playlists=  $youtube->playlists->listPlaylists('snippet', $queryParams_playlists);

foreach ($response_playlists->items as $playlistsid) {
    $id= $playlistsid->id;
    $ids[] = $id;

}
   
if(isset($response_playlists->nextPageToken)){
    $pagetoken=$response_playlists->nextPageToken;
    youtube_calls($pagetoken);
}
$queryParams_uploads = [
      'mine' => true
      ];

$response_uploads = $youtube->channels->listChannels('contentDetails', $queryParams_uploads);
foreach ($response_uploads->items as $uploadsid) {
     $upid= $uploadsid->contentDetails->relatedPlaylists->uploads;
     $ids1[] = $upid;
}

$total_ids=array_merge($ids,$ids1); 

}

function youtube_callsplaylistitems($pagetoken1){

global $youtube;
global $total_ids;
global $result;

if($pagetoken1!=''){
       $queryParams = [
    'playlistId' => $total_ids,
    'pageToken'=> $pagetoken
     ];
}
else{
     $queryParams = [
    'playlistId' => $total_ids];
}
 
$response = $youtube->playlistItems->listPlaylistItems('snippet', $queryParams);
foreach($response->items as $videos){
    $videoid=$videos->snippet->resourceId->videoId;
    $publishedat=$videos->snippet->publishedAt;
    $queryParams_videos= [
    'id' => $videoid];
    $response_videos = $youtube->videos->listVideos('snippet', $queryParams_videos);
    foreach($response_videos->items as $vids){
    $i=0;
    
    $description= $vids->snippet->description;
    $title= $vids->snippet->title;
    $thumbnail=$vids->snippet->thumbnails->default->url;
       $videoids[]= $videoid;
    $descriptions[]= $description;
    $titles[]=$title;
       $thumbnails[]=$thumbnail;
    }
 
   
if(isset($response->nextPageToken)){
    $pagetoken1=$response->nextPageToken;
    youtube_calls_playlist($pagetoken1);
}

   }
 
  
$result = array();
$values = array($videoids, $descriptions, $titles, $thumbnails);

foreach($videoids as $index => $key) {
    $t = array();
    foreach($values as $value) {
    $t[] = $value[$index];
}
    $result[]  = $t;
}
   print_r(json_encode($result));
 
}
?>
```

And the oauth2callback.php code is

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

session_start();

//$client = new Google\Client();
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAccessType('offline');
$client->setAuthConfigFile('client_secret_843932249311-9ittju7rjic43jh86g8talo2it8socj2.apps.googleusercontent.com.json');
$client->setRedirectUri('http://localhost/youtubeproject/' . 'oauth2callback.php/');

$client->setScopes([
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly',
]);

if (! isset($_GET['code'])) {
  $auth_url = $client->createAuthUrl();
  header('Location: ' . filter_var($auth_url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));

} else {
  $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
  $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
  $redirect_uri = 'http://localhost/youtubeproject/index.php' . '/';
  header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}

?>
```

I want to run it without any user interaction in cron job without any browser. Cant figure out how.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/youtube/registering_an_application says _You can generate OAuth 2.0 credentials for web applications, service accounts, or installed applications._ . What is the evidence for your statement that service accounts are not supported? Please provide a link to documentation and/or another reputable source to support your assertion. And...have you actually tried it?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/server-side-web-apps does add a caveat that _Note that the YouTube Data API supports the service account flow only for YouTube content owners that own and manage multiple YouTube channels. Specifically, content owners can use service accounts to call API methods that support the onBehalfOfContentOwner request parameter_ . So whether you can succeed may depend on what exactly you want to use the API for, but I don't see anything which is telling you that service accounts are completely unsupported.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/moving_to_oauth#service-accounts-do-not-work-with-the-youtube-api

Comment: I see, thankyou. It seems the documentation contradicts itself in different places, then!

Answer (score 1):

I update the code with getting access token and refresh token and save into a file and use it in cronjob without getting into browser and user interaction.

```php
<?php
$tokenFile = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\youtubeproject\token.txt';
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
session_start();


if (!file_exists(__DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php')) {
    throw new Exception(sprintf('Please run "composer require google/apiclient:~2.0" in "%s"', __DIR__));
}

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName('');
$client->setDeveloperKey("");
$client->setAccessType('offline');
$client->setScopes([
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly',
]);
$client->setAuthConfig('');

//$client->setApprovalPrompt('consent');
$client->setIncludeGrantedScopes(true);
$client->setPrompt('consent');
$client->setIncludeGrantedScopes(true);

// Load previously authorized credentials from a file.
if (file_exists($tokenFile)) {
    $accessToken = json_decode(file_get_contents($tokenFile), true);
    $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);
} else {
    if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) {
        $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);
        $accessTokenSaved = $client->getAccessToken();

        if (!file_exists(dirname($tokenFile))) {
            mkdir(dirname($tokenFile), 0700, true);
        }
        file_put_contents($tokenFile, json_encode($accessTokenSaved));
    } else {
        if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
            // the new access token comes with a refresh token as well
            $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
            $accessTokenUpdated['refresh_token'] = $refreshTokenSaved;

            // save to file
            file_put_contents($tokenFile, json_encode($accessTokenUpdated));
        }
    }
}

$youtube = new Google_Service_YouTube($client);

$i = 0;
$pagetoken = '';
$pagetoken1 = '';
youtube_calls_playlist($pagetoken);
youtube_callsplaylistitems($pagetoken1);

function youtube_calls_playlist($pagetoken)
{
    global $youtube;
    global $total_ids;
    if ($pagetoken != '') {
        $queryParams_playlists = [
            'mine' => true,
            'pageToken' => $pagetoken
        ];
    } else {
        $queryParams_playlists = [
            'mine' => true,
        ];
    }
    $response_playlists = $youtube->playlists->listPlaylists('snippet', $queryParams_playlists);

    foreach ($response_playlists->items as $playlistsid) {
        $id = $playlistsid->id;
        $ids[] = $id;
    }

    if (isset($response_playlists->nextPageToken)) {
        $pagetoken = $response_playlists->nextPageToken;
        youtube_calls($pagetoken);
    }
    $queryParams_uploads = [
        'mine' => true
    ];

    $response_uploads = $youtube->channels->listChannels('contentDetails', $queryParams_uploads);
    foreach ($response_uploads->items as $uploadsid) {
        $upid = $uploadsid->contentDetails->relatedPlaylists->uploads;
        $ids1[] = $upid;
    }

    $total_ids = array_merge($ids, $ids1);
}

function youtube_callsplaylistitems($pagetoken1)
{
    global $youtube;
    global $total_ids;
    global $result;

    if ($pagetoken1 != '') {
        $queryParams = [
            'playlistId' => $total_ids,
            'pageToken' => $pagetoken
        ];
    } else {
        $queryParams = [
            'playlistId' => $total_ids
        ];
    }

    $response = $youtube->playlistItems->listPlaylistItems('snippet', $queryParams);
    foreach ($response->items as $videos) {
        $videoid = $videos->snippet->resourceId->videoId;
        $publishedat = $videos->snippet->publishedAt;
        $queryParams_videos = [
            'id' => $videoid
        ];
        $response_videos = $youtube->videos->listVideos('snippet', $queryParams_videos);
        foreach ($response_videos->items as $vids) {
            $i = 0;
            $description = $vids->snippet->description;
            $title = $vids->snippet->title;
            $thumbnail = $vids->snippet->thumbnails->default->url;
            $videoids[] = $videoid;
            $descriptions[] = $description;
            $titles[] = $title;
            $thumbnails[] = $thumbnail;
        }

        if (isset($response->nextPageToken)) {
            $pagetoken1 = $response->nextPageToken;
            youtube_calls_playlist($pagetoken1);
        }
    }

    $result = array();
    $values = array($videoids, $descriptions, $titles, $thumbnails);

    foreach ($videoids as $index => $key) {
        $t = array();
        foreach ($values as $value) {
            $t[] = $value[$index];
        }
        $result[]  = $t;
    }
    print_r(json_encode($result));
}
?>
```